# configure and multiple threads

Tags: multithreading, compilation, makefile, configure

When I need to compile an application from sources (I'm talking in a linux environment) basically the procedure is the following:

- download and extract sources
- ./configure [optional params]
- make
- make install

Usually I pass `-j4` to `make` in order to use all the CPU resources and speed up (a lot!) the compilation process.

I'm wondering if there is something similar for `configure` which often takes a lot of time for execution. Of course I've already tried to pass the same option but it fails, and I find nothing related in `configure --help`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `configure` scripts generally do not conventionally allow for distributed or parallelized execution.

Results are usually cached in `configure.cache` so you might be able to refactor for parallel execution without too much effort.

If you want to save on running multiple configuration jobs for different libraries where they may run the same tests multiple times, have them share the same cache file.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Cache-Files.html

Comment: Thanks. I'm sure there is a technical reason for this. I don't need to relaunch the same `configure` command, but tipically I need to build a lot of different applications and the configuration time is quite long using only 25% of the CPU speed.